# Adding specific API responses to AsyncStorage in React Native on button press

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

In my React Native app i'm trying to add specific API responses to `AsyncStorage` on button press. Here's what my API request and save to AsyncStorage looks like:

```js
  onSearch = async () => {
    const results = await API.get(`/${searchText}`);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('favourites',JSON.stringify(results));
  }
```

And here's what i'm currently doing to save specific different responses to `AsyncStorage` on pressing save :

```js
  const onPressSave = async () => {
  //here's my current response data in variable data
    var data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('favourites')
    var favouriteData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('list')
    if (favouriteData === null) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('list',JSON.stringify(data))
    }else {
      var PreviousfavouriteData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('list')
      var allData = [data, PreviousfavouriteData]
      console.log('All Data >>>',allData )
    }
  }
```

This is only adding two responses to `allData` variable. How can i add more than two responses on pressing save button.

Comment: The code snippets don't work.

Comment: i have added the code snippet to give an idea of where i at. Its' showing two added data but not more than two. @tomasantunes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I hope it helps you.

```
const onPressSave = async () => {
   const storageKey = ['favourites', 'list', 'others'];
   let allData = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < storageKey.length; i++) {
       const tempData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKey[i]);
       const parseTempData = JSON.parse(tempData);
       if (parseTempData) {
        allData = [...allData, ...parseTempData];
       } else {
         // AsyncStorage.setItem() here
       }
   }
}
```